# SSRS taking long time to render the report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In my report I have Tablix1 with groups and detail.
The stored proc runs in less than 2 sec but reports takes longtime to render . Not sure what is  the reason.
Is it the aggregating values in SSRS?
Here is how my report looks.

```
School  50%  
   Grade  50%   
      Teacher   50%  
         Student   100%  
              Question1   100%  
              Question2   100%  
              Question3   100%  
              Question4   100%
```

Question level % is calculated in Storedproc. All above groups gets calculated in report.

Comment: does it have parameters? if yes, do you apply the filter at the dataset level or do you do it in the stored procedure?

Comment: Make sure your proc is not suffering from parameter sniffing.  Here's an article explaining what that is and some ways around it.  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added Recompile option in all the stored proc, removed page break . After that performance improved a little but not whole lot. Client is still unhappy with performance

Comment: bhupeshc- Filter is at stored proc level.

Comment: BhupeshC- I do have parameter at the stored proc level should I change it to dataset level? Please let me know.